# Dyadic expansion

Tags: limits, probability-theory

I'm reading the appendix in Billingsley book "Probability and measures" and I can't understand the following. If
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{d_i(\omega)}{2^i} < \omega \leq \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{d_i(\omega)}{2^i} + \frac{1}{2^n},\qquad \forall n\geq 1,\forall \omega\in(0,1]$$
then
$\omega = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{d_i(\omega)}{2^i}$

Here $d_1(\omega) = \begin{cases}0 & \omega\in(0,1/2]
 \\ 1 & \omega\in(1/2,1]\end{cases}$ and $d_i(\omega) = d_1(T^{i-1}(\omega))$ with $T(\omega) = \begin{cases}2\omega & \omega\in(0,1/2] \\ 2\omega - 1 & (1/2,1]\end{cases}$

In particular if this is true for any finite $n$, why we may pass to the limit and what happens with the first inequality, which is not strict?

Comment: What's $d_i$ exactly ? We are not all familiar with this particular book and his notation

Comment: I added details, but I'm not sure if this is relevant, since it does not depend on $n$. It looks like my question is probably a very basic one, namely, if $a_n<\omega \leq a_n + \frac{1}{2^n},\forall n\geq 1$, then why $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \omega$

Comment: Please suggest what can I improve in my question before downvoting.

Comment: $1/2^n\rightarrow 0$...

Comment: ...which gives me $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{d_i(\omega)}{2^i} < \omega\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{d_i(\omega)}{2^i}$, but what about the first strict inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$d_i(\omega)$ is the $i$th binary digit of $\omega$.

Let $S_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{d_i(\omega)}{2^i}$, and let $S = \sum_{i = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{d_i(\omega)}{2^i}$.

Then 
$$S - S_n = \sum_{i = n+1}^{+\infty} \frac{d_i(\omega)}{2^i} \leq \sum_{i = n+1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} \leq \frac{1}{2^n}.$$

It follows from this that
$$ S_n \leq S \leq S_n + \frac{1}{2^n}.$$

Since $\omega$ satisfies the same inequalities as $S$, we must have $|S - \omega| \leq \frac{1}{2^n}.$ As this is valid for all $n$, we must in fact have $\omega = S$.